# Открытие блока при нажатии

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, вёрстка

Добрый день.

У меня есть несколько элементов списка:

```html
<li>
  <a href="#">
    <span class="background-text"></span>
    <span>Amazing video</span>
  </a>
  <div class="additional-text">
    Lorem...
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#">
    <span class="background-text"></span>
    <span>Amazing video</span>
  </a>
  <div class="additional-text">
    Lorem...
  </div>
</li>
```

Мне нужно реализовать так: При нажатии на `<span class="background-text">`, должен открыться один блок `.additional-text`, который находится внутри первого `li` (изначально у блока `.additional-text` стоит стиль `display: none`), при нажатии на второй `<span class="background-text">`, открываться `.additional-text` только внутри второго `li`.

При любой попытке реализовать (с учетом добавления `id` или без), почему-то отображаются все существующие `.additional-text` на странице. Как можно это обойти?

Заранее большое спасибо.

Comment: Приложите, пожалуйста, используемый вами js-код и css-стили.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы открывать относящийся к отпределенной "кнопке" блок, нужно искать его в общем родителе. Сделать это можно, используя метод `.closest()`.

```js
$('.background-text').on('click', function() {
  var add = $(this).closest('li').find('.additional-text');
  $('.additional-text').not(add).slideUp(400); // сворачиваем все блоки, кроме необходимого
  $(this).closest('li').find('.additional-text').slideToggle(400); // разворачиваем необходимый блок
});
```

```css
.background-text {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #000;
}

.additional-text {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <span class="background-text"></span>
      <span>Amazing video</span>
    </a>
    <div class="additional-text">
      Lorem...
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <span class="background-text"></span>
      <span>Amazing video</span>
    </a>
    <div class="additional-text">
      Lorem...
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Также посоветовал бы вам вешать событие клика не на `span`, а на `a`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Все отлично работает!

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, еще подсказать такое: как реализовать так, что бы одновременно нельзя было открыть несколько блоков (при нажатии на кнопку у меня открывается блок)? т.е. так, что бы всегда был открыт только один, а если пользователь хочет открыть другой, то первый закрывался.

Comment: @Kate обновил ответ